# Use optional parameters in $state.go

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a website by AngularJS and ui-router. I have defined 2 states as follows:

```
.state('home', {
       url: '/home/{id}',
       ...
})
.state('edit', {
       url: '/edit/{id}?connected&ifIni&redirectToRun',
       ...
```

In a controller, I could use `$state.go('home', { id: id })` to navigate to the `home` page.

My question is if I could use e.g., `$state.go('edit', { id: id, connected: connected, ifIni: ifIni, redirectToRun: redirectToRun })` to navigate to the `edit` page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in two differnet ways, one is by adding `params` in `routeConfiguration` and other is to add as `query parameters` to `URL`

**Adding Params:**

Route Configuration:

```
$stateProvider.state('edit', {
  templateUrl:'edit.html',
  controller:'editController',
  params: {
    'id': ''
    'referer': '', 
    'connected': '', 
    'ifIni': '',
    'redirectToRun': ''
  }
});
```

Redirection:

```
$state.go('edit', { id: id, connected: connected, ifIni: ifIni, redirectToRun: redirectToRun })
```

---

**If you want to use Query params:**

Route Configuration:

```
$stateProvider.state('edit', {
  url: '/edit/{id}?connected&ifIni&redirectToRun',
  templateUrl:'edit.html',
  controller:'editController'
});
```

Redirection:

```
$state.go('edit', { id: id, connected: connected, ifIni: ifIni, redirectToRun: redirectToRun })
```

[**Here is the Documentation**](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/url-routing)

Comment: yes, you should take `params` in route configuration

Comment: I also added answer using query params